# Error: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

estoy teniendo problemas para **imprimir** los datos ingresados en un modal. La información ingresa bien en la base de datos, comprobé que se guarde y si funciona este modal.
El problema surge cuando deseo *editar los datos guardados*, que tambien lo hago mediante un modal.

**Para ingresar los datos** este es el código:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="miModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
          <h1 class="modal-title fs-5">Nuevo cliente</h1>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
       
          <div class="modal-body">
          <form method="POST" class="agg-cliente mb-1" action="botonesClientes.php" id="addCliente">
              <?php include('../errors.php'); ?>

              <div class="mb-3">
                    <label class="form-label">Localidad</label>
                    <select name="idLocalidad" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                      <option value="0">Seleccionar localidad</option>
                      <?php
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM localidades";
                        $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
                    
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row['nomLocalidad'];?>"><?php echo $row['nomLocalidad'];?></option>;
                      <?php } ?>
                    </select>
              </div>

              <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label">Nombre</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Ingresar nombre">
              </div>

              <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label">Apellido</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellido" name="apellido" placeholder="Ingresar apellido">
              </div>

              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Dirección</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="direccion" name="direccion" placeholder="Ingresar direccion">
              </div>

              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Telefono</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="telefono" name="telefono" placeholder="Ingresar telefono">
              </div>

            <!-- Botones de modal -->
              <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal" name="btn-cerrar">Cerrar</button>
                  <input type="submit" name="btnGuardar" class="btn btn-primary" value="Guardar">
              </div>
          </form>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

El **modal para editar** los datos es el siguiente. El **mensaje de error** salta en los value=""; de los campos nombre, apellido, direccion y telefono. Tal como:

value="
**Warning**:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema-aleph\clientes\editarClientes.php** on line **50**
">

value="
**Warning**:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema-aleph\clientes\editarClientes.php** on line **55**
">

value="
**Warning**:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema-aleph\clientes\editarClientes.php** on line **60**
">

value="
**Warning**:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema-aleph\clientes\editarClientes.php** on line **65**
">

```
<?php 

    if(isset($_GET['editarClientes']))
    {
        $idCliente = $_GET('editarClientes');
        $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE idCliente='$idCliente'");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        
        $idCliente = $row['idCliente'];
        $idLocalidad = $row['idLocalidad'];
        $nombre = $row['nombre'];
        $apellido = $row['apellido'];
        $direccion = $row['direccion'];
        $telefono = $row['telefono'];
        
    }
?>


<div class="modal fade" id="editarClientes<?php echo $row['idCliente']; ?>" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="modalTittle">Editar clientes</h1>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form method="POST" class="agg-cliente mb-1" action="botonesClientes.php" id="addCliente">
                        <?php include('../errors.php'); ?>
                        <input type="hidden" name="idCliente" value="<?= $row['idCliente']; ?>"> 

                        <div class="mb-3">
                                <label class="form-label">Localidad</label>
                                <select name="idLocalidad" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                                <option value="0">Seleccionar localidad</option>
                                <?php
                                    $query = "SELECT * FROM localidades";
                                    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
                                
                                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $row['idLocalidad'];?>"><?php echo $row['idLocalidad'];?></option>;
                                <?php } ?>
                                </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label class="form-label">Nombre</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Ingresar nombre" value="<?php echo $row['nombre'];?>">
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label class="form-label">Apellido</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellido" name="apellido" placeholder="Ingresar apellido" value="<?php echo $row['apellido'];?>">
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Dirección</label> 
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="direccion" name="direccion" placeholder="Ingresar direccion" value="<?php echo $row['direccion'];?>">
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Telefono</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="telefono" name="telefono" placeholder="Ingresar telefono" value="<?php echo $row['telefono'];?>">
                        </div>

                        <!-- Botones de modal -->
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal" name="btn-cerrar">Cerrar</button>
                            <button type="submit" name="actualizar" class="btn btn-primary" value="Actualizar">Actualizar</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Me parece que falta un `SELECT` en ese contexto. Yo veo esto: `SELECT * FROM localidades` y luego un `while` para llenar los datos de las localidades. Eso supongo que funciona. El error viene porque intentas usar `$row` para leer `nombres`, `apellidos`, etc, pero no hay ningún `SELECT` que te traiga esos datos. Debes hacer un `SELECT` y luego un `while`, del  mismo modo que haces con las localidades.

Comment: Ya intente hacer eso, el error desaparece pero no me trae los datos guardado, sigo en la misma. De hecho tengo otro código que es igual y el otro si me trae la información, no entiendo porque en este que tengo no me los imprime

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y pon cómo tienes el código ahora.

Comment: Ahí lo modifique, podes volver a ver como tengo el codigo en el archivo para editar los datos.

Answer (score 0):

**Saludos**

De lo que observo en tu código donde creas no usas `$row`; pero donde editas sí.

*El problema*

Donde editas tienes:

```
<input type="hidden" name="idCliente" value="<?= $row['idCliente']; ?>">
```

pero no se ve ese primer $row donde lo inicializas; ahora más adelante tienes el `while` del bloque php siguiente:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM localidades";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){?>
   <option value="<?php echo $row['idLocalidad'];?>"><?php echo $row['idLocalidad'];?></option>;
<?php } ?>
```

Observa que allí durante ese bucle poblas `$row`. Recuerda que ese bucle termina cuando mysqli_fetch_array retorna false (valor booleano); por tanto saliendo de ese ciclo en

```
<div class="mb-3">
   <label class="form-label">Nombre</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Ingresar nombre" value="<?php echo $row['nombre'];?>">
</div>
```

y líneas subsecuentes donde te marcar error `$row` es un booleano y no un array (asociativo) con los datos que en su momento tuvo con:

```
<input type="hidden" name="idCliente" value="<?= $row['idCliente']; ?>">
```

*Sugerencia*

Cambia en tu bloque (antes mencionado) del `while` el `$row` a (por sugerirte un nombre) `$rowW`:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM localidades";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

while($rowW = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){?>
   <option value="<?php echo $row['idLocalidad'];?>"><?php echo $rowW['idLocalidad'];?></option>;
<?php } ?>
```

Esta sugerencia por ser la más rápida y no buscarías en tus `input` pudiendo quedarte alguno por cambiar.

Espero te sea de utilidad u orientación.

Comment: Roberto, yo creo que el error es otro: falta un nuevo `SELECT` para obtener los datos de los clientes. No creo que en la tabla `localidades` haya campos como `nombre`,  `apellido`, etc.

Comment: exacto, en realidad los campos de nombre, apellido, etc. estan guardados en la tabla de clientes

Comment: Saludos @Brenda y @A.Cedano  no incluí ese `SELECT`, al inicio no lo incluye en su código; asumí Brenda sabe su origen y por ello sugerí solo cambiar de nombre el `$row` a `$rowW` usado en el `while`.